raspberry pi does not boot when UART(RX/TX) connected via serial
I am using ubuntu 20.04 server LTS on raspberry 4. I have pixhawk flight controller connected via TX/RX on raspberry pi GPIO14(TXD) GPIO15(RXD).I write a mavproxy.service to forward telemetry data to laptop via wifi. Now on restart the raspberry pi is not booting up I think it goes to comsole mode. I want to get pixhawk data via GPIO on ubuntu 20.04 server

I’m voting to close this question because you're using Ubuntu instead of RPi OS. In some cases, this (using Ubuntu) would not be an issue, but it is here because Ubuntu does not have the same device tree, overlays and firmware as used in the RPi OS. And so, unless you can explain - in your Question - how that is set up, it makes it v. difficult to answer.
